# How do I stringify array type properties of a Java object using package org.json

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

I am trying to stringify a typical Java object using the [toString()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29) method from org.json. However, Collections or Array type members in my beans are stringified in the form of byte arrays. I have set out a sample code to illustrate the problem.

Here is what I do expect:

```
{
   "nonWorkingDays":[
      "Saturday",
      "Sunday"
   ],
   "workingDays":[
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
   ],
   "days":[
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7
   ]
}
```

And here is what I am getting instead:

```
{
  "nonWorkingDays": [
    {
      "bytes": [
        {},
        {}, ...
      ],
      "empty": false
    },
    {
      "bytes": [
        {},
        {}, ...
      ],
      "empty": false
    }
  ],
  "workingDays": [
    {
      "bytes": [
        {},
        {}, ...
      ],
      "empty": false
    },
    {
      "bytes": [
        {},
        {}, ...
      ],
      "empty": false
    }, ...
  ],
  "days": [
    {},
    {}, ...
  ]
}
```

Finally, here is my code:

```
/* Week.java */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Week {
    private List<String> workingDays = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String[] nonWorkingDays;
    int days[];

    public Week() {
        String[] workingDaysArray = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
        workingDays.addAll(Arrays.asList(workingDaysArray));
        nonWorkingDays = new String[] { "Saturday", "Sunday" };
        days = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    }

    public List<String> getWorkingDays() {
        return workingDays;
    }

    public String[] getNonWorkingDays() {
        return nonWorkingDays;
    }

    public int[] getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Week [workingDays=" + workingDays + ", nonWorkingDays=" + Arrays.toString(nonWorkingDays) + ", days="
                + Arrays.toString(days) + "]";
    }
}

/* WeekTest.java */

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class WeekTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        Week myWeek = new Week();
        JSONObject myWeekJSON = new JSONObject(myWeek);
        String myWeekJSONString = myWeekJSON.toString(2);
        System.out.println(myWeekJSONString); // Formatted JSON string
        System.out.println(myWeek); // Output from Week's toString()
    }
}
```

Btw, the Week's toString() method output's the following:

```
Week [workingDays=[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday], nonWorkingDays=[Saturday, Sunday], days=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Edit:

The problem seems to be with [this maven artifact](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211). After updating to the source from [this github repo](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) I got everything fixed. Please see comment below.

Comment: Tested your code, worked for me - I have the correct display. Maybe there is a bug in your `org.json` library ?

Comment: Thanks Chafouin. Your guess is correct. I have been using [this maven artifact](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211) which is the latest on maven repository as of yet. But that release is probably outdated.  After using the source from [this github repo](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) my program started to work as expected. I found the link to this repo from json.org website. However, no maven artifact seems to be available for this latest source code.